# Run pip package via absolute path

Tags: unix, pip

On my `Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS` I have installed `pipenv` package using `pip` package manager. Package is accessible from ssh login bash.

`$ pipenv --version`

will print out following output:

> pipenv, version 2018.10.13

**What want:**

I need to run `$ pipenv --version` command using absolute path. So This is how it should look like:

`$ /absolute/path/to/pipenv --version`

However so far it looks like it does not work by this way.

**What I tried:**

```
$ pip show pipenv
```

> **Name**: pipenv
>
> **Version**: 2018.10.13
>
> **Location**: /user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
>
> **Requires**: enum34, virtualenv, typing, certifi, virtualenv-clone, pip, setuptools
>
> ...

I copied location from output above, and I tried these, but still does not work:

- `$ /user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipenv --version`
- `$ /user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipenv/pipenv --version`

**I also tried:**

`which pipenv` - outputs empty string

Comment: `which pipenv`?

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: That's strange, `pipenv --version` works but `which pipenv` outputs nothing - is this an alias or even a function? Does `type pipenv` output something? As an alternative, you can run `pip show -f pipenv`, which should print all files installed with `pipenv` package. You should be able to see the executable among other files, smth like `../../../pipenv`. Combine this path with the one printed in the `Location:` line and you should get the path to the executable. Probably `/user/.local/bin/pipenv` in your case, but can't say for sure.

Comment: @hoefling basically the path to executable is printed using `type pipenv` as you suggested. If you want, feel free to create an answer. I will accept gladly! Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recapping the comments, if `pipenv` command is available, you can:

1. run `command -v pipenv` or `which pipenv` if `pipenv` is an executable in `PATH`
2. run `type pipenv` if `pipenv` is an alias or a function

If the command is not available, you can extract the info about the executable from the package metadata: run

```
$ pip show -f pipenv
```

to list the files belonging to the `pipenv` package (If the output is empty, it means that `pipenv` is not installed for the Python version `pip` refers to). Among other things, it will print you the package location, similar to

```
Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages
```

and with other files, the executable:

```
../../../bin/pipenv
```

This is the path relative to the `Location` above - the resolved path leads you to the executable file.